# Attempting to compare textbox with array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to compare user entered text in a textbox with an element in an array but am having difficulties.

```
function checkAns()
{
var str = imageArray[randNum];
var n = str.indexOf(document.getElementById('textBox').value);
if(n == -1)
{
    alert("Wrong Answer")
}
else
{
    alert("Right Answer")
}
}
```

The user input should either match part of the the specified string in the array element and return Right Answer or not match at all and return Wrong Answer.

```
<input type=”text” id=”textBox” value=””>
<input type=”button” value=”Check” onclick=”checkAns()”>
```

I added the code for my textbox and button if that is useful.

Comment: `str.indexOf(document.getElementById('textBox').value;` is missing a closing parenthesis for `indexOf`.

Comment: Oh thanks, I included that in my code I just forgot it here.

Comment: Use `console.log` and the developer console to debug javascript, it'll give you interactive feedback for objects and arrays.

Comment: What error are you getting? Check firebug/ or ie/chrome developer tools

Comment: When I click the button to run checkAns() nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check what exactly you need to get. This:

```
if (document.getElementById('textBox').value === str) {
    // text from array element is the same as in value
} else {
    // ... differs from value
}
```

Or this:

```
if (str.indexOf(document.getElementById('textBox').value) > -1) {
    // text from value exists in array element
} else {
    // ... does not exist
}
```

Or maybe this:

```
if (document.getElementById('textBox').value.indexOf(str) > -1) {
    // text from array element exists in value
} else {
    // ... does not exist
}
```

Comment: I believe the second example is the kind of code I was looking at.